# How to activate first item on page load in sly plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, sly-scroller

I have a requirement where I need a slider with horizontal scroll bar. So I ended up with Sly plugin. But I am facing issues because 4th item is always been selected in the carousel. I want to remove this selection and activate the first item on page load. Also is there a way to customize the scroll bar too in such a way if user clicks or drags to the third item, scroll bar stays under the third item, which means if am in first item, scroll bar should be that small to fit just under the first item not till middle or end.

Comment: Can you add up the code which you have written for initialization ?? Or a link for example ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to add up the startAt parameter in your sly initialization.
For example suppose the name of the div is frame and you want to add sly to this div.

```
var $frame = $('.frame');
var sly = new Sly($frame, {
    // Your other sly related params
    startAt: 0,   /// This will force the sly to start from first item.
});
```

Rest of the stuffs which you mentioned in your question that is impossible to answer as it will require some more clarification.

Comment: Didn't work. The plugin still activates the 4th slide not the first one.

Comment: Add your initialization code here and show me your code.. Also look for errors in console.

Comment: No errors in the console. I am using the same code mentioned above.